# Spark streaming on YARN executor's logs not available

Tags: logging, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, spark-streaming

I'm running the following code

```
.map{x => 
    Logger.fatal("Hello World")
    x._2
 }
```

It's spark streaming applciation runs on YARN. I upadted log4j and provided it with spark-submit (using --files). My Log4j configuration was loaded which I see from logs and applied to Driver's logs (I see my log level only and my pattern in logs), however logs from executors are not available. I can't find "Hello Word" in logs. Also, I checked ${yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs} and it's empty which looks strange. Where is my log?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution, the proper `log4j` configuration must be set in the following way during the application submit:

```
--files /opt/spark/conf/log4j.properties
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties"
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties"
```

where

```
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions   -> sets up log configuration for driver
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions -> sets up log configuration for executor(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the official *Spark* documentation ([link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#debugging-your-application)), there are two ways *YARN* manages the logging:

- If log aggregation is turned on  (with the `yarn.log-aggregation-enable config`):

Container logs are deleted from the local machines (executors) and are copied to an *HDFS* directory. These logs can be viewed from anywhere on the cluster with the `yarn logs` command, in the following manner:

```
yarn logs -applicationId <app ID>
```

- If log aggregation is **not** turned on:

Logs are maintained locally on each machine under `YARN_APP_LOGS_DIR`, which is usually configured to `/tmp/logs` or `$HADOOP_HOME/logs/userlogs` depending on the *Hadoop* version and installation. According to the documentation, viewing logs for a container requires going to the host that contains them and looking in this directory.

Comment: In my case, log aggregation is turned on, but I can't see my logs using either yarn logs or web UI. and it's strange